Filter_select of crosstalks- not working for shared data with key
I am wondering if there is any work around to make a filter_select work on a shared DF with key.
For example, you may see here (checking the datatable) that the filter is not working correctly. It only works if I define no key for the shared DF or if I define the key same as the filter (species).
Am I doing anything wrong?
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)



shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(iris, ~Petal.Length,group = "a")

bscols( 
  filter_select("species", 
                "Species:",shared_df1,~Species,multiple=FALSE),

 subplot(plot_ly(shared_df1) %>% add_markers(x=~Petal.Length, y=~Petal.Width)),
         
 datatable(shared_df1)
)

